# How to return a filtered subset of an observablearray to a drop down box based on a radio button selection

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, single-page-application, singlepage

I have a drop down box and a radio button that are part of a detail row.  There can be multiple detail rows, so there can be multiple instances of this radio button and drop down list.  I have an observablearray that is a master list of loans of types 'dl' and 'sb'.  The 'dl' and 'sb' are the values on the radio buttons.  When a user selects a radio button, i want to populate the drop down box with a list of the loans that have the loan type selected ('dl' or 'sb') from the radio button.  So, for example, if a user selects the radio button that has the value of 'sb,' then I want to populate the drop down list on the selected detail row with only those loans that are 'sb' loan types (in the observable, a field called DocStandBy is tied to the loan type, and LoanNum in the same observable is the loan number to be displayed in the drop down box).

I have not been able to figure out how to return a filtered subset of an observablearray to a drop down box based on a click event on a radio button.  Below is code that obviously does not work, but does illistrate what I am trying to do.  How can I alter the below code to get this to work?

VIEW-

```
                         <tbody data-bind="foreach: LoanDetails()">
                        <tr style="border: none">
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: DocStandby, attr: { 'name': SeedID(), 'value': 'DL' }, click: $parent.SaveDocStand($data)" />
                                Documentary
                                    <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: DocStandby, attr: { 'name': SeedID(), 'value': 'SB' }, click: $parent.SaveDocStand($data)" />
                                Stand By

                            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr style="border: none">
                            <td style="font-weight: bold">AB Loans:</td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="ddlLoans" data-bind=" optionsCaption: 'Choose...', 
                options: $parent.ABLoans($parent.dlOrSB() == $data.DocStandby()), optionsText: 'LoanNum',
                    optionsValue: 'LoanNum'">
                                </select>
            </td>
                        </tr>
           </tbody>
```

VIEWMODEL EDITED-

```
  define(['services/logger', 'durandal/system', 'plugins/router', 'services/CertificateDataService', 'controls/Lucas', 'services/ErrorLoggingDataService',  'services/LCDataService'],
function (logger, system, router, CertificateDataService, Lucas, ErrorLoggingDataService, LCDataService) {

    var clients = ko.observableArray([]);
    var ABLoans = ko.observableArray([]);

    var clientID = ko.observable();
    var LoanDetails = ko.observableArray([]);

    var dlOrSB = ko.observable();


    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        clients: clients,
        LoanDetails: LoanDetails,
        ABLoans: ABLoans,
        dlOrSB: dlOrSB,
    clientID: clientID,
   AddLC: function () {

            nextnum(nextnum() + 1);
            LoanDetails.push(buildRow(nextnum(), vm.LCLoans, 'DD'));

     },
    SaveDocStand: function (row) {

            if (row.DocStandby() != null && row.DocStandby() != '') {
        //POPLUATES ABLoans observablearray, or THE MASTER LIST OF LOANS
                GetLoansByClient(row.DocStandby(), clientID(), 'AB');
            }

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(LoanDetails(), function (item) {


                if (item.SeedID() == row.SeedID()) {
                    item.FilteredLoans = ko.computed(function () {
                        var val = row.DocStandby();
                        return LCLoans().filter(function (item) {
                            return val && item.LoanSubType === val;
                        });
                    })



                }
            });


            dlOrSB = row.DocStandby();



        }
 };
```

Comment: What is the structure of each element of LoanDetails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of your LoanDetails array needs to have a separate computed that returns a filtered array of your ABLoans based on the selected DocStandby.

You will notice that each element of LoadDetails has its own ko.computed ( FilteredLoans ) that just returns a filter based on the value of the DocStandby observable.  It uses a common source of loans ( ABLoans ) so if that array was ever to be updated then all line item computed will also re-filter.

Here is a basic example that shows you the mechanics invoked, you will need to adapt to your exact object model, specifically how you create your LoadDetail array items.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: LoanDetails">
        <tr colspan="2">
            <td><input type="radio" data-bind="checked: DocStandby, attr: { 'name': SeedID(), 'value': 'DL' }" />Documentary
                <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: DocStandby, attr: { 'name': SeedID(), 'value': 'SB' }" />Stand By</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>AB Loan:</td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: FilteredLoans, value: LoanNum, optionsValue: 'LoanNum', optionsText: 'LoanNum', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var vm = {
    LoanDetails: ko.observableArray([]),
    ABLoans: ko.observableArray([])
};

var buildRow = function( seed, ABLoans) {
    var obj = {
        SeedID: ko.observable(seed),
        DocStandby: ko.observable(),
        LoanNum: ko.observable()
    };

    // Add to object after obj is created so we can use that instance
    // using "this" to read the items DocStandby value
    obj.FilteredLoans = ko.computed( function() {
            var val = this.DocStandby();
            return ABLoans().filter( function( item ) { 
                return val && item.Type === val;
            } );
        }, obj);

    return obj;
};

vm.ABLoans( [
    { LoanNum: '1-DL', Type: 'DL' }, 
    { LoanNum: '2-DL', Type: 'DL' }, 
    { LoanNum: '1-SB', Type: 'SB' }, 
    { LoanNum: '2-SB', Type: 'SB' }, 
] );

vm.LoanDetails.push( buildRow(1, vm.ABLoans));
vm.LoanDetails.push( buildRow(2, vm.ABLoans));

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv3fL/) for the above code working

Comment: You have me on the right track, but need to do something a little different.  Your code populates SeedID, DocStandby, LoanNum AND FilteredLoans at the same time.  My users click an Add button and add empty rows.  I coded it as you have it, but create an empty row each time buildrow is called.  On a click event tied to the radio button, I want to populate FilteredLoans  at that time.  Can you take a look at my edit and tell me how I can populate FilteredLoans in my LoanDetails observeablearray in the SaveDocStand function?

Comment: I just re-added the edit.  The AddLC method adds a blank row, the SaveDocStand is where I need to populate the FilteredLoans I create in AddLC.  And thanks for answering!

Comment: see "VIEWMODEL EDITED"

Comment: You can't re-assign the FilteredLoans computed inside that function, Knockout won't detect the change. Convert FilteredLoans to an observableArray (created in buildRow) and set its value in your SaveDocStand function.  With the exception of the call to GetLoansByClient you are doing exactly the same thing in my answer, as  call to `ko.utils.arrayForEach(LoanDetails())...` should only ever process 1 item, so why the loop.  Lastly why is the MasterList being reset on every radio click.  Either ABLoans belongs inside each row, or it shouldn't be reset per click.  Is `GetLoansByClient` async?

Comment: You have a few variables and functions used but not declared in the sample.  `vm.LCLoans` and `buildRow` and `GetLoansByClient`.  Adding these will fill in some context and I can update my example to match your exact scenario

Comment: Got it to work.  Modified your code to fit my scenario.  Thanks Robert!